# How can I concatenate two XML tags using Ruby/Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xml, parsing

I am using Ruby to retrieve an XML document with the following format:

```
<project>
  <users>
   <person>
     <name>LUIS</name>
   </person>
   <person>
     <name>JOHN</name>
   </person>
  </users>
</project>
```

I want to know how to produce the following result, with the  tags concatenated:

```
<project>
    <users>
      <person>
        <name>LUIS JOHN</name>
      </person>
    </users>
</project>
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
file = File.new( "proyectos.xml" )
doc3 = Nokogiri::XML(file)
a=0

@participa = doc3.search("person")
@participa.each do |i|

     @par = @participa.search("name").map { |node| node.children.text }

     @par.each do |i|
         puts @par[a]
         puts '--'
         a = a + 1
    end 

end
```

Comment: This is the second time you've asked the same question, and the first instance was closed because you did not show any code you wrote which would tell us that you have made an attempt to solve the problem. As is, it appears you are fishing for code to solve your problem without having made a true effort, which is not how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: ok i will put my code and show how i parse the rest of the document thnak by the advice and sorry can i use this question or i should make a new question??

Comment: Edit your question and append your code to it. Thanks. We don't need everything, just the code that attempts to read the XML, and parse and modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than supply code, here's how to fish:

To parse your XML into Nokogiri, which I recommend highly:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<project>
  <users>
   <person>
     <name>LUIS</name>
   </person>
   <person>
     <name>JOHN</name>
   </person>
  </users>
</project>
EOT
```

That gives you a `doc` variable which is the DOM as a Nokogiri::XML::Document. From that you can search, either for matching nodes or a particular node. `search` allows you to pass an XPath or CSS accessor to locate what you are looking for. I recommend CSS for most things because it is more readable, but XPath has some great tools to dig into the structure of your XML, so often I end up with both in my code.

So, `doc.at('users')` is the CSS accessor to find the first `users` node. `doc.search('person')` will return all nodes matching the `person` tag as a `NodeSet`, which is basically an array which you can enumerate or loop over.

Nokogiri has a `text` method for a node that lets you get the text content of that node, including all the carriage-returns between nodes that would normally be considered formatting in the XML as it flows down the document. When you have the text of the node, you can apply the normal Ruby string processing commands, such as `strip`, `squish`, `chomp`, etc., to massage the text into a more usable format.

Nokogiri also has a `children=` method which lets you redefine the child nodes of a node. You can pass in a node you've created, a NodeSet, or even the text you want rendered into the XML at that point.

In a quick experiment, I have code that does what you want in basically four lines. But, I want to see your work before I share what I wrote.

Finally, `puts doc.to_xml` will let you easily see if your changes to the document were successful.

---

Here's how I'd do it:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<project>
  <users>
   <person>
     <name>LUIS</name>
   </person>
   <person>
     <name>JOHN</name>
   </person>
  </users>
</project>
EOT
```

The XML is parsed into a DOM now. Search for the `users` tags, then locate the embedded `name` tags and extract the text from them. Join the results into a single space-delimited string. Then replace the children of the `users` tag with the desired results:

```
doc.search('users').each do |users|
  user_names = users.search('name').map(&:text).join(' ')
  users.children = "<person><name>#{ user_names }</name></person>"
end
```

If you output the resulting XML you'll get:

```
puts doc.to_xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project>
  <users><person><name>LUIS JOHN</name></person></users>
</project>
```

Comment: thanks i will try this solution. Sorry neverless i want make the question in a good way.How can i send you the new question for your comment?? It's only to imporve my skill making question. thanks again. Could you wait until tomorrow before share your code i will try my own solution.

Comment: I can't solve it i get all valuesbut  no the values of the node particular could you share yout code please

Comment: I added the solution I'd use.

Comment: I tried this solution and was that i need thanks you are save me i was blocked.